# Prove me wrong: VB.NET HtmlHelper Extension Method NOT Working in MVC 4 with VS 2012

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, extension-methods, html-helper

No matter how many times I try, I cannot get my HTML Helper extension method to work.  Here's the test steps I've created, if someone wants to try it out themselves:

1. Using Visual Studio 2012, I create a new "Visual Basic ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Web Application" using the "Internet Application" project template.
2. I create a folder `"~/Views/Helpers"`
3. I create a file `"DisplayForPropertyHelper.vb"` and add the following code:

   ```vb
   Namespace TestProject.Extensions
       Public Module HtmlHelperExtensions
           <Extension()>
           Public Function DisplayForProperty(helper As HtmlHelper) As MvcHtmlString
               Return MvcHtmlString.Create("TEST")
           End Function
       End Module
   End Namespace
   ```
4. I open up `"~/Views/Web.config"` and change the following (I add the extensions namespace):

   ```xml
   <system.web.webPages.razor>
       <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
       <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
         <namespaces>
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
           <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
           <add namespace="TestProject.Extensions"/>
         </namespaces>
       </pages>
   </system.web.webPages.razor>
   ```
5. Compile the project
6. Choose ANY razor view file, and type `@Html.Display`-and you will see that the extension method does not show up.
7. Add to the razor view file `@Imports TestProject.Extensions` then save and close the file.
8. Reopen file, and type `@Html.Display`-and you will see that the extension method does not show up.
9. You can even try closing VS2012 and reopening the project.  Won't make a difference.

I have been battling with this for weeks now.  All answers I've found on here and elsewhere are NO help.  Someone must have an answer.

Comment: How about having the class outside of Views folder? i.e. have a new folder as same level as that of Controllers and Views. Also, the web.config of the root should be modified for this for extension methods to be visible throughout the project.

Comment: Try it.  It doesn't make a difference.  I tried creating it in a root folder `"~/Extensions"`, didn't change anything.  I tried the same namespace addition in my root `"~/Web.config"` and still nothing.

Comment: I am sorry. I realize that I shouldn't be commenting on VB.net related questions.

Comment: It's cool - I appreciate you trying to help!  Was frustrated with the code, not your response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that you prefixed your namespace with your application name. So for example if the application you created was called `MvcApplication1` in your `~/Views/web.config` you should put:

```
<add namespace="MvcApplication1.TestProject.Extensions"/>
```

and not just:

```
<add namespace="TestProject.Extensions"/>
```

Yeah, I guess, it's one of those VB.NET thingies :-) Oh and don't forget to close and open the Razor view after making changes to the `~/Views/web.config` file, otherwise your changes won't be taken into account immediately (if you run the application it will work of course).

Comment: Holy moley.  That worked, like a charm.  You, sir, are a god amongst men.

Comment: Is this required for C# as well?  If not, any idea why?  Every answer I came across mentioned nothing about prefixing with application name.

Comment: No, of course that this is not required in C#. In C# when you declare a class inside a namespace this class is actually declared in the namespace you asked for it (DUH). I am not an expert in VB.NET (actually hate the language) but I guess it has to do something with those Modules.

Comment: I'm noticing some other bizarre behavior that is probably specific to VB.NET...When I create a new controller in an Area, it specifies the root namespace of the project as the namespace of the class in the boilerplate code.  So, for instance, if your project is named `TestProject.Web`, then the controller you create "DefaultController" is created under `TestProject.Web.TestProject.Web.DefaultController`.  Not sure if the same thing happens with C#, though.

Comment: No, of course that the same thing doesn't happen in C#. As I already told you such things don't happen in C#.

Comment: I'm on the similar frustrating issue - of course, with VB.Net! I tried all the above said! But still no luck. When the system was in MVC3, it was happy. We just migrated to MVC4 - then on Razor is not recognizing these helpers. The web project has root namespace defined as 'Root', assembly name as 'MainApp' & project name as 'MainApp.Web'. To my knowledge, used all the permutations & combinations for no success. I did ensured closing the View & reopening every time I changed web.config. I changed the config file under 'Views' folder. Any thoughts please?

Comment: Further verification about this issue resulted in finding that my project still referring to MVC3 dll. I replaced it with MVC4 dll - all is well :) Sorry if I bothered...

Comment: Just to note, I was having a similar problem in C# MVC4 but the fix was to close the view an re-open it (as Darin mentions towards the end of the answer). Before doing that I could only get it work by adding `@using...` to the view no matter how many times I re-built the project. Most infuriating!

Answer (score 4):

This is not really an answer, but I write it here in hopes to only add (a little) the overall picture.

**For me, I discovered that my 'Module' class was not explicitly being modified as 'Public'** (the default is Friend when you don't specify a modifier, and that was what was killing mine)

Yes, I realize the O.P.'s example Module is already declared Public already.. but, I just didn't catch it in my own code stack and figured I'd highlight that requirement. As a native C-sharper having to play VB.Netter for the past five years, I get tired of translating C# snippets manually.. and tend to rely on [code converters](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/). So, the nifty HtmlHelper I found and converted didn't quite come out right and I neglected to look for this issue in the code snippet that had been generated for me.

As noted in the prior comments, I'd also like to join the chorus and state the following:

- I was doing all of the above (so I thought, as I checked the O.P.'s checklist over and over)
- I also find writing HtmlHelpers nearly impossible for VB.NET MVC 4 (until today) - the requirements seem to be supported in such a fragile manner
- I also despise having to use VB.NET for developing MVC sites (but, I must live with it.. it's part of the legacy code I inherited coming on board my company)
- As much as I despise it (for reasons like this one) I will say everything does seem to be supported if you are determined enough to figure it out. (thanks StackOverflow!)

Prior to this discovery, I thought maybe it wasn't working because my application name had dots in it (MyCorp.Web.WorkOrders) vs. (MvcApplication1).. but, my tests conclude that the application name was not the issue. Either way you name it, it will work.

Again, as @Darin already pointed out..  you certainly must include the solution name(space) as part of the 'add namespace' declaration in views/web.config